# Preview files in ranger

Tags: ranger

I have been able to preview images in ranger. But for some reason I don't have file preview. Not for any type of files. Not for compressed files either. I'm running linux mint and ranger v1.7.1. How do I preview files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in man

```
     preview_files [bool] <zp>
     Preview files in the preview column?
```

I try `zp` in v1.7.1, it works

what I did

```
    git clone https://github.com/ranger/ranger.git
    cd ranger
    git reset --hard v1.7.1
    python ranger.py -c 
    # -c for clean config
```

Comment: Yeah, I found out long ago, thankyou. But I changed

`set use_preview_script false`
to 
`set use_preview_script true`

and I don't have to `zp` anymore. I don't know why the script messes things up. I'm using the default script anyway.

Comment: I had the opposite problem. It tried to show previews, but previews for some files would crash ranger. So I needed to disable previews. Thanks